# How to fetch documents from two different subcollections

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a small app for car maintenance notes.
Now I want to fetch all car maintenance records from Firestore Database, but my code doesn't work correctly.
I have a collection "Vehicles". This collection stores all vehicle documents. Every vehicle has a subcollection "MaintenanceItems", and inside this subcollection, there are some documents. I need to fetch all documents inside "MaintenanceItems" for every vehicle and display them on the screen.
I wrote the class "ExpensesManager" for it, but there is a problem. After adding a new MaintenanceItem I get duplicates.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

class ExpensesManager: ObservableObject {
    private(set) var expenses = [MaintenanceItem]()
    @Published private(set) var expenseItems = [MaintenanceItem]()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    init(vehicles: [Vehicle]) {
        fetchExpenseItems(vehicles: vehicles)
        print("ExpensesManager init func succeess!")
    }
    
    func fetchExpenseItems(vehicles: [Vehicle]) {
        for vehicle in vehicles {
            guard let vehicleID = vehicle.id else {
                print("VehicleID is not found")
                return
            }
            
            db.collection("Vehicles").document("\(vehicleID)").collection("MaintenanceItems").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
                guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                    print("Error fetching documents: \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                
                print("Documents are received")
                
                self.expenses = documents.compactMap { document -> MaintenanceItem? in
                    do {
                        return try document.data(as: MaintenanceItem.self)
                    } catch {
                        print("Error decoding document into Expense: \(error)")
                        return nil
                    }
                }
                
                for expense in self.expenses {
                    self.expenseItems.append(expense)
                }
                
                print("Expenses array is completed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For clarity, your question states  - *I need to fetch all documents inside "MaintenanceItems" for every vehicle* - for what purpose? If you're doing this as part of the apps features, why not just have a top level collection that contains that data? Then getting them all is a snap. Each document can have an field that references the vehicle document it's tied to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to fetch all documents inside "MaintenanceItems" for every vehicle and display them on the screen.

If you need to get all documents that exist inside all `MaintenanceItems` collections, basically the maintenance items of all vehicles, then you should consider using a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

```
db.collectionGroup("MaintenanceItems").addSnapshotListener { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Hey Ilia. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped me. But now I got a new problem. When my data in Firestore has changed, the ExpensesView didn't reload.

Comment: Good to hear that, Ilia.

Comment: If you have a hard time implementing something, please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.